# value of type 'AnyObject' has no member age

Tags: swift, core-data

here is my code for a program which actually worked for one other application but here when I am using again it is saying Value of type 'AnyObject' has no member 'age'

this is the code i used to save the data to coredata

```
            let user = User(context: context)
            user.name = username.text!
            user.age = Int16(userage.text!)!
            appDelegate.saveContext()

            print("user name and age saved")
```

below I am using action button to retrieve core data

```
@IBAction func retrieve(_ sender: UIButton) {

    do {
        let data = try context.fetch(User.fetchRequest())

        for each in data {

        print("Name : \((each as AnyObject).name! ?? "name!")\nAge : \((each as AnyObject).age!)\n")
        }
    }
    catch {
        // handle error
    }
}
```

please help me where I am wrong also swift seems unpredictable when using 'User' of CoreData entity sometimes it did not detect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not cast up the concrete type `User` to unspecified `AnyObject`

```
print("Name : \(each.name)\nAge : \(each.age)\n")
```

If you get compiler errors consolidate the generic syntax of `FetchRequest`

Comment: No that is not correct, swift force you to accept each as AnyObject

Comment: Then your Core Data environment is wrong. `fetch` with a generic request is supposed to return an array of the associated type. Try this syntax : `try context.fetch(User.fetchRequest()) as! [User]`